# Socket with Proxy in Python 3.4

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, python-3.4

I have a code that I want to pass all packages through the proxy, how can I do it using:

```
import socket
import #Here your socket library
# The rest of the code here
```

Which library do you recommend me to use with Socket? Is it really possible what I'm saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Socksipy in Python 3.4 I can let the code with 3 more lines that are:

```
 import socksipy
 s=socket.socket( )
 s = socks.socksocket()
 s.setproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, 'localhost', 9050)
 s.connect((HOST, PORT))
```

Socksipy can be found at: http://socksipy.sourceforge.net/ and its very simple to use, you just need to read their wiki so than you can work with. The URL for the wiki is: https://code.google.com/p/socksipy-branch/